# Why does Ruby have the "Array#<=>" but not "Array#<"?

Tags: ruby

You can compare two arrays like this.

```
p ([1, 2] <=> [1, 3]) < 0 # [1, 2] < [1, 3]
p ([1, 2] <=> [1, 3]) > 0 # [1, 2] > [1, 3]
p ([1, 2] <=> [1, 3]) == 0 # [1, 2] == [1, 3]
```

I wonder why there are no operators like `>`, `<`, etc. Is it an intentional design or not? If it is, what is the history on it?

Comment: Matz rejected the idea: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5574

Comment: I'm curious: can you come up with a real-world example where you would compare arrays via `<` or `>`? Of course, I can create contrived examples but I can't think of an actual use case.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for the link. That answers the question. If you don't mind, I'll answer my own question based on it. The array comparison is useful when you use an array as a key of the data structure, such as a priority queue(heap).

Answer (score 1):

My five cents to OP comment:

> The array comparison is useful when you use an array as a key of the data structure, such as a priority queue(heap).

In that case I would prefer to have an explicit logic for that. For example:

```
class Key
  attr_reader :array

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end

  def <(other)
    (array <=> other.array) < 0
  end

  def >(other)
    (array <=> other.array) > 0
  end

  def ==(other)
    (array <=> other.array) == 0
  end
end

key1 = Key.new([1, 2])
key2 = Key.new([1, 3])

p key1 < key2
p key1 > key2
p key1 == key2
```

Comment: Alternatively you can include `Comparable` and delegate `<=>` to `@array`

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question based on the information provided by Stefan.

It was an intentional design by Matz, the original author of Ruby. Comparing two arrays by comparing elements in lexicographical order is a natural and useful idea. But they are not always comparable, like this example.

```
p [1, 2] <=> [1, 'x'] # This returns nil, because you can't compare 2 and 'x'.
```

Matz was concerned that providing ordinary comparison operators would give a false impression that arrays are always comparable. But he couldn't give up comparing arrays entirely and provided the special `<=>` operator. You can read his answer on the related feature request at [Feature#5574 - Make arrays comparable](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5574#note-7).

So the design decision was an opinionated one rather than a technical one. In my humble opinion, it would be more consistent if ordinary operators are provided and an exception is raised when arrays are not comparable. (I'm a fan of both Ruby and Python.)

Comment: Speaking of consistency: `Hash` implements `<` and `>` (in regards to subset / superset) but not `<=>`, i.e. you can compare hashes but not sort them. `Module` also has custom `<` and `>` semantics (based on ancestor relation) but _does_ implement `<=>`.